# Any production ready JMS failover (HA) for JBoss 5.1 EAP available?

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss5.x, hornetq

We are using HornetQ as JMS provider in JBoss 5.1 EAP and in general we are quite satisfied with HornetQs performance.

HornetQ dropped data replication support in 2.2.2 silently. Now, we have problems creating a HA solution with JBoss and HornetQ as the present HornetQ failover strategies aren't reliable. For example, clients have problems to reconnect to the HornetQ after the master is back online. Messages are stored in a store-and-forward queue when using a round-robin strategy and this leads to undelivered messages in a case of a node shutdown.

HornetQ is evolving, but without data replication no serious solution for a productive environment.

Which JMS provider support real production safe HA and failover capabilities in conjunction with good performance, monitoring and of course JBoss 5 interoperability?

Answer (score 1):

We have been supporting our users using GFS, which would be way more reliable than replication since it guarantees a singleton instance running between life and backup at any point.

We are working towards replication. We have the code working and it should be released shortly. But shared storage has been proved to be very reliable.

We are going to support replication, but IMHO shared storage is the best solution for most of the cases. The only scenario where this is not true is when there's no way to invest on the disk that will support GFS (or any other shared and high available disks).

We have big banks using this solution in production environments. As you said we are making progress. These banks actually would use the hardware solution (including disaster-recovery datacenter) even if replication was already supported.

Comment: I am in doubt about using shared storage as fallback strategy. If the journal gets corrupted during a hardware fail, the failover node (slave) won't be able to use the storage.

Clebert, what is your experience in corrupted HornetQ data in a HA setup?
We used GFS in the past with a lot of problems, which finally let to remove GFS. Have you used DRBD for storage synchronization?

Comment: I haven't used DRDB myself.

The only case I can think of a corruption on the journal is if you have a crash on the disk, but as far I understand those GFS disks should be replicated and resilient to failures.

As for a software failure, we have been testing HornetQ and the latest version has proven to be stable.

We are working on finishing the replication. Sorry we can't offer you that option at the moment, but we are working on it.

Comment: Also: another option would be something through NFS. I just got a confirmation from our kernel team that AIO should work fine over NFS, as long as it supports O_DIRECT on the file.

Comment: For what it's worth, my company has dropped HornetQ from evaluation because of the requirement for a shared disk. We have a data centre with plenty of hardware, but no shared disks. HornetQ would require us to reconfigure the hardware to use it; RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ do not. I think this is a shame, because HornetQ is otherwise an excellent piece of software, but this was a showstopper for us.

Comment: @TomAnderson We will have replication ready very soon. It's actually ready.. we are just polishing it now

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Inevitably, i will be involved in evaluating messages again in the future, and then, i look forward to being able to argue for HornetQ. At a tangent: have you ever considered a storage backend that used a fast, distributed key-value store (eg Riak)? It might not be as fast as the native journal, but it would perhaps be an easy way to get solid replication with good performance.

Comment: @TomAnderson: I have been thinking of big-data for other reasons. But I don't want to give up details in public now as it may spoil the idea.. Why don't you look for me on irc/freedone / hornetq?

Comment: Will do. But not before you get the release with replication out. Wouldn't want to distract you :D.

Comment: @TomAnderson: yep.. we will finish replication first :)